# Production (heroku, postgres) #find_in_batches query running at long intervals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, delayed-job

I've got a job (which is queued up using DelayedJob) for deleting med-large amounts of records.  On production, the job is running extremely slowly, deleting around 1200 records per hour.  At first, I just destroyed and re-ran the job, then ran heroku restart (in case it was running into a memory leak issue or something), but nothing changed.

Looking at the logs, I noticed that each batch was running exactly 4 minutes and 40 or 41 seconds after the last one, but I can't find any setting anywhere that would be responsible for this.  When I run the same job in development, it deleted all 100k records in just a minute or two.

Is there some setting for this that I'm missing, or something else I'm overlooking?  Here's the relevant part of the job code in case it provides any clues.

```
total_deleted = 0
Record.where(...).includes(...).find_in_batches(batch_size: 100) do |group|
  Record.transaction do
    group.each do |record|
      record.destroy
    end

    total_deleted += group.size
    percentage = (total_deleted.to_f / total.to_f * 100).round
    self.update_attribute(:details, "Deleted #{total_deleted} of #{total} (#{percentage}%)")
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you getting memory related errors from your worker dyno when this happens? Heroku dynos only have 512mb of memory by default, and it's really easy to max that out, causing your dyno to use swap memory, which is very slow.

Comment: @DanielWestendorf No, and that's part of what makes this so confusing.  My worker dyno is showing an average memory use of ~25% and a max of 26% for the past few hours that the query has been running.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you run this code via a console session? Is your postgres instance pegging CPU or Memory? Does your `Record` model have a lot of dependent associations that have to get destroyed? Additionally, you might like [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) more than `find_in_batches`.